# XDocReport : ODT generated with wrong values

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, odt, xdocreport

I've generate ODT with XDocReport version 1.0.6, in result, the ODT file contain some wrong values.

Here is a part of my initial template in ODT :

```
C.A du gérant du $bean.beginDay au $bean.endDay $bean.month : $bean.ca
```

The java bean contain :

```
private int beginDay;
private int endDay;
private String month;
private Double ca;
```

With getters and setters

In Java controller method, i've put the bean in context like that :

```
IContext context = report.createContext();
context.put("bean", reportBean);
```

And the part of ODT result :

```
C.A du gérant du fr.golt.amodin.commun.reports.MonthReports2016@68ab6bf4.beginDay au fr.golt.amodin.commun.reports.MonthReports2016@68ab6bf4.endDay Juin : 64841.4
```

the attributs beginDay and endDay are wrong. i've the same error for others attributs. have you an idea how to correct it ?

Thank's

Comment: Are you sure that you are using Input Field like explained in https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/ODTDesignReport#create-field-with-oppenoffice ?

Comment: Thank's, i've used this sample : 
[link]https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki, i've test for 1 field and it works, i'll change the rest of fields and i'll see if it works